# Can't import own Python module

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am currently running on python 3.6 on anaconda. I have a project structure where `(test/lib/yolo/yolo_model.py)` and `(test/car/detection/cpu_yolo_detector.py)`.

I run my main from the test directory. My main now calls the script cpu_yolo_detector.py from withing `(test/car/detection)`.

From cpu_yolo_detector.py I want to access the yolo_model.py with

"`from lib.yolo.yolo_model import YoloModel`" 
but I get "`no module named lib.yolo`".

At the beginning of the main.py I add `('C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\test\\lib\\yolo')` to the sys.path and I still get that Error.

I tried both python 3.6 and 3.7 aswell as a virtual environment and without a virtual environment. If I run it with PyCharm everything seems to work but from the terminal it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried adding the directory route to the PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: yeah that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `test/` is the root of your project structure. If you want

```
from lib.yolo.yolo_model import YoloModel
```

to work, then the directory containing `lib/` must be in `sys.path`.

Try adding `'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\test'` to sys.path.

Comment: Honestly, I am so stupid to not have seen that. Thanks alot works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the two files (module and main file) in the same directory. If the module name is helpermodule
on main write:

```py
import helpermodule
#or import a specific class/method you might need
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because this is quite a massive project with a lot of scripts being called from different directories. I would end up having to put everything into one folder and i don't want to do that.

Comment: Provide an example is a better way to answer instead of writing only a sentence

Comment: Its pretty self-explanatory, but sure, Ill update and provide an example.